# How can the "Suggested For You" feature of Google News be disabled?

Tags: google-news

For the last couple of months Google News has been offering me a section entitled "Suggested for you", containing one news item.  This occurs when I am logged into my Google account on any browser on any machine.

[image: Screenshot of section heading]

So far, every single day, it has suggested an item in which I have no interest whatsoever.  It is time consuming and irritating to click '*No*' on the "Are you interested?" question every day.

I cannot find anywhere in any settings menu the facility to remove "Suggested for you" completely.  I can only find options to re-enable the suggestions that I have blocked - which currently runs to well over 100 items.

Is there a setting somewhere to remove this item?

Answer (score 1):

> **[Stop seeing stories based on past searches](https://support.google.com/news/answer/1146405?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)**
>
> There are several ways to stop Google News from showing stories based on your past searches and browsing activity on Google:
>
> - Sign out of your Google Account.
> - Browse in incognito (or private) mode.
> - Delete activity from your account.
> - Turn off Web & App Activity.